# Disable plugin-container in Firefox 43

Tags: flash, firefox, plugins

Prior to using 43 version of Firefox, I could just delete plugin-container.exe and flash player was working fine. Now I am using Firefox 43 and when deleting plugin-container.exe, flash player no longer works, it only shows a black square.  The only way for "flash player" to work on FF43 is if I dont delete plugin-container.exe meaning that flash player only works along with plugin container. I dont like pluin-container, specially when using VPN sercive, because it does uncanted firewall requests.

Any solution to the problem? I dont install flash player, I just grab the NPSWF32...dll file and put it into "plugins" folder of firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FF 38 (from June '15) was the last version that allowed you to disable plugin-container.exe from `about:config` - just visit this bug to see why: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1194780

Download 38.0.5: http://filehippo.com/download_firefox/61544/
Developer version: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/

Check out the recent IE version, it is much faster...FF is great and all but performance and stability isn't priority number one or two.